# How to check Sharepoint Document Properties using VBA

Tags: vba, sharepoint, properties

[image]

I am looking to develop code to view the document properties of a file on SharePoint, then later build out this code to see if it matches the document properties of the `ActiveWorkbook`. Below is a sample of the code I have so far which is able to filter through to the correct document in the SharePoint Library. Does anyone know the function which must be added to `objFile` to access the SharePoint Document properties?

```
Sub CheckVersion()
Dim FSO As Object
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim objFile As Object
Dim objDSO As Object

For Each objFile In FSO.GetFolder("\\SharePoint\Library\").Files
    If objFile.Name = "FileName.zip" Then
        MsgBox (objFile.Properties.Title)
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: do you mean sharepoint listitem properties for document in document library?

Comment: Yes, the properties associated with the document on SharePoint. Not the file properties if you opened it up off of the web.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming SharePoint 2010 and higher version.

Use SharePoint REST Services to get proper data items with desired properties.

[REST Services Reference for Sharepoint 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx)

[REST API Reference for SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569.aspx)

Get items from list using SharePoint 2010:

`http://lab/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/List1()?$filter=startswith(Title,'foo')&$top=1&$select=Title,Column2,Column3`

Get items from list using SharePoint 2013

```
http://lab/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List1')/items?$filter=startswith(Title,'foo')&$top=1&$select=Title,Column2,Column3
```

Then you have to request this url with VBA (remeber to add references to `Microsoft WinHTTP Services, version 5.1` and `Microsoft XML, v6.0`)

```
URL = "http://lab/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/List1()?$filter=startswith(Title,'foo')&$top=1&$select=Title,Column2,Column3"

Set req = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
req.Open "GET", URL, False
req.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/xml"
req.SetCredentials "login", "pass", 0
req.Send

Set objXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DomDocument.6.0")
If Not objXML.LoadXML(req.ResponseText) Then
    Err.Raise objXML.parseError.ErrorCode, , objXML.parseError.reason
End If
```

XML parsing is for you ;)

/edit

To filter element with your filename, use:

```
http://lab/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Library()?$filter=FileLeafRef eq 'FileName.zip'&$select=Title
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Just to confirm, all this code would be required to access the "title" properties in the snapshot I included in my question?

Comment: proper REST call is required. web request in VBA is required, xml reading is also required :) I'll update my code to match your filename filter